# Using QGIS Python Console in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, mac, qgis-python-console, keyerror

I'm pretty new to using the console and still have a lot to learn so this might come across as a really stupid question.

I imputed this code into the console:

```
counter = 0

# Set the path for the output file
output_file = open(r'/Users/admin/Desktop/TestFlood.txt', 'wb')
iter_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test_flood')
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() 

for point in iter_layer[0].getFeatures():
   counter += 1
   print(counter)

   for layer in layers:
       if layer.name() != iter_layer[0].name():
           for feature in layer.getFeatures():
               if (feature.geometry().contains(point.geometry())):
                   msgout = '%s, %s \n' % (point["pcds"], layer.name())
                   unicode_message = msgout.encode('utf-8')
                   output_file.write(unicode_message)

print('Finished')
output_file.close()
```

I am trying to run a few thousand points through each of the layers I have created and get an output on a text file that I can use to analyze further. And added a counter to see how long it takes as when I first ran this it took around a week. However, when I run it this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode    
exec(code, self.locals)  
File "input", line 1, in 'module'  
File "string", line 31, in 'module'
KeyError: 'pcds'
```

This is probably very simple to fix but I have searched online for a while and couldn't find anything to help.

I am using QGIS 3.4.9-Madeira and my OS is MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave.

Answer (score 3):

This line is causing the error
`msgout = '%s, %s \n' % (point["pcds"], layer.name())`

Without seeing the data, I'm assuming your point file doesn't have a column named 'pcds'

Renaming it to the correct column should solve the error.